# C++11 templates code - failed to compile in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I have this code:

```
template<bool, class _Ty1, class _Ty2> struct MyIf
{   // type is _Ty2 for assumed false
    typedef _Ty2 type;
};

template<class _Ty1, class _Ty2> struct MyIf<true, _Ty1, _Ty2>
{   // type is _Ty1 for assumed true
    typedef _Ty1 type;
};

template<class _Ty>
struct my_decay
{
    // determines decayed version of _Ty
    typedef typename std::decay<_Ty>::type _Ty1;

    typedef typename MyIf<
        std::is_arithmetic<_Ty1>::value, typename _Ty1, //(1)
        typename MyIf<
            std::is_same<LuaString, _Ty1>::value, typename _Ty1, //(2)

        typename _Ty //(3)
        >::type
    >::type type;
};
```

Under Visual Studio 2015, it compiles fine. However, when I port my code to XCode, I got the following errors:

> - for (1) => Expected a qualified name after "typename"
> - for (2) => Type name does not allow storage class to be specified
> - for (3) => Type name does not allow storage class to be specified

In Xcode, I have set C++ laguage dialcet to GNU++14, C++ standard library to C++11 support and used compiler is Apple LLVM 8.1.

Comment: Looks like MSVS is letting you add extra `typename`s.  If you remove those 3 `typename`s does it compile?  Also, just a FYI, MSVS is not the most standard conformant compiler out there.  g++/clang have much better conformance.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right, stupid mistake, thank you.. post it, please, as an answer.

Comment: And stop using reserved identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `my_decay` `Ty` and `_Ty1` are not qualified names.  That means you do not need to use `typename` on them.  It looks as though MSVS is allowing you to do so for some reason. Either it is a bug or they consider it a "feature" so people can just spray `typename` everywhere to get it to work.  The correct version should be:

```
template<class _Ty>
struct my_decay
{
    // determines decayed version of _Ty
    typedef typename std::decay<_Ty>::type _Ty1;

    typedef typename MyIf<
        std::is_arithmetic<_Ty1>::value, _Ty1, //(1)
        typename MyIf<
            std::is_same<void, _Ty1>::value, _Ty1, //(2)

        _Ty //(3)
        >::type
    >::type type;
};
```

---

Also, you should stay away from using leading underscores in your identifiers.  A leading underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for the system as well as all identifiers with a double underscore in them.

Comment: Of course `_Ty` and `_Ty1` are dependent types; by definition, the type denoted by a template parameter depends on that template parameter. The issue is that you need - and can - only use `typename` on qualified names.

Comment: @T.C. Fixed the answer.  Thanks for the correction.